# FolderBrowserDialog change

Tags: c#, winforms

does anyone know why my folderbrowserdialog is look like this

[FolderBrowserDialog](https://imgur.com/a/Be5JiqH.png)

Code:

```
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
              
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.pdf");
```

and why not like this

[what i want](https://imgur.com/a/EJvCrsu.png)

Edit: my problem solved.
i am using filter , "*.pdf" but it does not show in the folder as you can see in the first picture it does not display pdf file. thats why im using the other UI of folder browser

Comment: Show us the properties as they appear in the _designer._

Comment: here https://imgur.com/a/lxDjMbv.png

Comment: I do not understand why you would want the later variant. Being able to paste a path instead of being *forced* to browse it is great.

Comment: @JonasH i am using filter , "*.pdf"  but it does not show in the folder as you can see in the first picture it does not display pdf file .

Comment: If you want to browse for *files* you should not be using a dialog for *folders*. If you want to open a file I would suggest `Microsoft.win32.OpenFileDialog` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoUpgradeEnabled` in `folderBrowserDialog` to `False`